# How do I access variables from another class in Java?

Tags: java

I have a class called Customer with customerName, customerEmail and customerAddress as variables set in an object called a. How do I print the variables customerName, customerEmail and customerAddress in another class called BookingConfirmation? I tried:

```
System.out.println("Thanks for your booking " + a.getCustomerName());
```

Here is the code for Customer class:

```
public class Customer {

String customerName;
String customerEmail;
String customerAddress;
    
    public static void customerDetails() throws IOException {
        
        Customer a = new Customer();
    
        Scanner seekName = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.print("Your name: ");
        a.customerName = seekName.nextLine();  // Read user input
            
        Scanner seekEmail = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.print("Your email: ");
        a.customerEmail = seekEmail.nextLine();  // Read user input
            
        Scanner seekAddress = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.print("Your residential address: ");
        a.customerAddress = seekAddress.nextLine();  // Read user input
        

        System.out.println("Thanks for your booking " + a.getCustomerName());
        System.out.println("Eemail: " + a.getCustomerEmail());
        System.out.println("Address: " + a.getCustomerAddress());
        System.out.println();
    }
    
        public String getCustomerName() {
            return customerName;
        }
        
        public String getCustomerEmail() {
            return customerEmail;
        }
                
        public String getCustomerAddress() {
            return customerAddress;
        }
                
}
```

Comment: Theoretically you can't access a local variable(in this case ```a```) from outside its scope. In your example the object ```a``` has method scope and won't be accessible from outside customerDetails() function.

Comment: You should return that `Customer` object you made in your static method, and then you have a valid factory pattern. Also, encapsulate your fields (make them `private`, look up getters and setters)

Comment: What you can do is change the return type of ```customerDetails()``` to ```Customer``` instead of ```void```, and return the object ```a```. And try accessing it from within your  ```BookingConfirmation``` class.

Comment: how do i return object a and access it from BookingConfirmation class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to access the value of a property from outside of the class, then you need to create getters for each one of the properties you want to retrieve.

If you want to modify these values from outside of the class, you need to create a setter.

Getters and Setters are simply methods that allow you to access properties of a class outside of it.

If you have the class `Customer` and want to access and change it's name from outside, you'd create 2 methods,

```
//declare the property
private String name;

//getter
public String getName(){
   return this.name;
}

//setter 
public void setName(String newName){
   this.name = newName;
}

//You can then instantiate a Customer object anywhere else and have access to those //properties

Customer cust = new Customer();
cust.setName("Mark")
System.out.println("Oh hi " + cust.getName());
//output "Oh hi Mark"
```

Read more on [getters and setters](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp)

Also, best practices tip: instance variables should always be declared as `private` to help encapsulation. If no access modifier is provided for an instance variable in Java, it defaults to the `default` modifier, which makes the variable accessible for every class within the same package.

Edit:

Your specific error is that you are creating a new `Customer` object within your `customerDetails` method, and you're not returning this `Customer` object. Therefore, as soon as the method has been executed, the `Customer` object you created inside is destroyed (cleared from memory,Garbage collected), because there is no further reference to it.

You either need to

Method 1: Change the return type of your customerDetails method from `void` to `Customer` and add a `return a` statement at the end, then you would simply need to instantiate a Customer object from your booking class, like so

```
public Customer customerDetails(){               
    Customer a = new Customer();           
    //your logic to set all of the properties          
    return a;        
}
```

**in your booking class**

```
Customer myCust = new Customer();
myCust = myCust.customerDetails();
```

I would not prefer this method, because as you see, you're just creating an empty object then reassigning to it. You may alternatively add the `static` keyword after `public` so that you can call it without having instantiated an object of the class, like so

booking class

```
Customer myCust = Customer.customerDetails();
```

Method 2: remove the `Customer a = new Customer()` from the customerDetails altogether and simply use `this.name = sc.nextLine()` to set the name of whatever instance is calling this method.

Then on bookings class, instantiate a new Customer object and call the method.

```
Customer myCust = new Customer();
myCust.customerDetails();
```

Comment: I thought I did create getters for all 3? Do I need to create the getters in the BookingConfirmation class?

Comment: You did create getters. My answer is simply going over both so that it is more informative for the general public.

Now, what does your print statement prints?

Comment: The `System.out.println("Thanks for your booking " + a.getCustomerName());` code is located in the BookingConfirmation but to get the customerName from Customer should I use `Customer.getCustomerName()` instead? Would you mind typing the code I would need to use in BookingConfirmation class to access the getter from Customer class for customerName?

Comment: If you use `Customer.getCustomerName()`, that's a static method. You don't have a static method. A static method is one which is called from the class itself, rather than from an instantiated object of the class.

I see what your error is.
You are creating the new `customer` object within your `customerDetails` method, and this method does not return anything.
The customer object you're creating is being destroyed right after that method is over, because you're not holding any reference to it.

You need to change that method to return a `Customer`

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep it with a return value of void, but you must create a customer instance within your booking class by using something like Customer myCust = new Customer()

Then you can call your customerDetails method on that object to set it's variables, and then you can retrieve them with the getter.

Comment: How do I change the method to return a customer? Would you be able to show the code needed for that?

Comment: I have already provided the code for that, it is in the edit section of my answer, please review my entire answer again. Methods have their return type specified after their access modifier. So `public Customer methodName() {}` is a method that returns an object of type Customer.

Comment: I would also like to ask: are you learning programming by yourself or as part of a university course? If it's the latter, I would seriously consider grabbing your text book and revisiting the first chapters. I'm not saying this to discourage you, but rather, to stop you from making the mistakes I made when I learned.  Your knowledge at the moment is a block of Swiss cheese. It might look like it's solid but it's full of holes. Methods/functions and classes are at the heart of object oriented programming. You should dominate this before going any further or you will develop bad practices.

Comment: If I use the code in your first example, how would I populate the object with data received from keyboard input via the Scanner?

Comment: If you use the code from the first example where im telling you to return the customer object, that object will already have all of the data from the scanner. Where I said "//your logic to set all of the properties" I meant instead of that comment, you just put the normal logic you had at the start. Your logic to set those fields wasn't wrong, what was wrong was the fact that you were not returning the customer object that you were creating in customerDetails, but everything relating to the inputs was correct.

Comment: Keep in mind that, at the end of the day, everything you put into a scanner boils down into a string. A scanner ReadLine returns whatever you write into it as a string. So if you wanted to, you could even have your scanner in your booking class and store each field in a separate variable, then you'd just pass each variable to each of your setter methods for your object. That's also entirely valid like your approach.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I know what you're asking, but it seems that you could do the following:

1. Have the `customerDetails()` method return `a` (the created Customer object) as the result of the method.
2. Call `Customer.customerDetails()` from `BookingConfirmation`, and save returned value in a local variable `Customer a`.
3. Then you can call `System.out.println("Thanks for your booking " + a.getCustomerName());` inside the `BookingConfirmation` code.

Comment: I just want to copy the 3 variables from Customer class and print them in sentences (using system.out.println() all done in terminal) in BookingConfirmation class. Scanner gets name in Customer class. BookingConformation class prints. "We have received your hotel booking (name from Customer class - variable customerName).